Issue with Previewing Multiple Images After Upload in React
I'm working on a React component that allows users to edit a product and upload images. While I'm able to set and preview a single image correctly, I'm having trouble with previewing multiple images. Specifically, the images do not display as expected right after the upload. On line 78 the console.log does log the array of base 64 images, but I don't know why it is not previewing it.
Here's my code snippet:
"use client"
import { usePathname } from 'next/navigation'
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { useEffect } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'
import { OrbitProgress } from 'react-loading-indicators'
import Image from 'next/image'
import { render } from 'react-dom'
const EditContent = () => {
  // Get Data //
  const path = usePathname();
  const pathQeury = path.split("/");
  const id = pathQeury[3];
  const [fetched,setFetched] = useState(false);
  const [products,setProducts] = useState([])


  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get(`/api/OneProductGet/${id}`)
    .then((response) =>
     {setProducts(response.data);
        setFetched(true);
     })
    .catch((error) => console.error(error))
  },[id])
  console.log(products)
  //-------------------------------------------//


    // Data //
    const [title, setTitle] = useState("");
    const [description, setDescription] = useState("");
    const [price, setPrice] = useState(0);
    const [singleImage, setSingleImage] = useState(null);
    const [multipleImages, setMultipleImages] = useState([]);
    const [SingleImageSrc, setSingleImageSrc] = useState();
    const [MultipleImageSrc, setMultipleImageSrc] = useState([]);
    let MultipleImagesSrc = []; 
    let MultipleImages = [];
    //------------------------------------------------------//
    
    
// Tranforme Single Image Data To src //
    useEffect(() => {
      if(singleImage){
        const render = new FileReader();
  
        render.onload = (e) => {
          setSingleImageSrc(e.target.result);
        }
        render.readAsDataURL(singleImage);
      }
      else{
        setSingleImageSrc(products[0]?.images[0]);
      }
    },[singleImage,products[0]])
    console.log(SingleImageSrc)
//-------------------------------------//

// Function Of Handling Multiple Images //


MultipleImages.push(...multipleImages);


useEffect(() => {
  if(MultipleImages){
    MultipleImages.map((image) => {
      const render = new FileReader();

    render.onload = (e) => {
      setMultipleImageSrc(e.target.result);
    }
    render.readAsDataURL(image);
    MultipleImagesSrc.push(MultipleImageSrc);
  })
  }
  console.log(MultipleImagesSrc)
},[MultipleImages])
//--------------------------------------//
// Function Of Handling Data //
async function handleSubmit(){
  const formData = new FormData();

  formData.append('title', title);
  formData.append('description', description);
  formData.append('price', price);
  formData.append('singleImage', singleImage);
  formData.append('multipleImages', multipleImages);
}






    
    if (!fetched){
        return( 
        <div  className='flex justify-center items-center bg-white w-full m-5 rounded-lg ml-0 p-5'>
            <OrbitProgress color="#1e3a8a" size="medium" text="" textColor="" />
        </div>
        );
    }
  return (
    <div className=' bg-white w-full m-5 rounded-lg ml-0 p-5'>
        <h1 className=' ml-2 text-3xl mb-4 font-semibold text-blue-900'>Edit Product</h1>
      <form className='flex flex-col  gap-1' onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <label className='ml-1 text-blue-900 '>
          Product name <span className='text-red-500'>*</span>
        </label>
          <input required={true}  className='mb-2  border p-1 rounded-lg' type="text" name="title" placeholder={products[0]?.name}/>
        <label className='ml-1 text-blue-900 '>
          Description 
        </label>
          <textarea className='mb-2  border p-1 rounded-lg' name="content" rows="4" cols="50" placeholder={products[0]?.description} />
        <label className='ml-1 text-blue-900 '>Price (in MAD) <span className='text-red-500'>*</span></label>
        <input required={true} className='mb-2  border p-1 rounded-lg' type="number" name="price" placeholder={products[0]?.price} />
        
        <label className='text-blue-900'>Main Product Image  <span className='text-red-500'>*</span></label>
        <div className='grid grid-cols-4 gap-3'>
          { SingleImageSrc? (
            <div className='relative group h-full w-full flex rounded-xl overflow-hidden border-2'>
              <img
              
              src={SingleImageSrc}
              
              alt='hello'
              ></img>
              <div className='group-hover:opacity-20 transition-all bg-black h-full absolute opacity-0 w-full'></div>
              <button className=' absolute right-0' onClick={() => {setSingleImageSrc(undefined)}}>
                <i class='bx bx-x text-red-500 invisible  group-hover:visible absolute m-2 text-[30px] right-0'></i>
              </button>
            </div>
          ) : (<div className='hidden'></div>
          )}
          <div className='flex flex-col justify-center items-center text-center py-14 px-5 overflow-hidden relative border-dashed border-2 rounded-lg h-full '>
            <i class='bx bx-cloud-upload text-blue-900 text-[3em]'></i>
            <p className='w-[80%] '><span className='opacity-60'>Drop your images here or select</span> <span className='text-blue-900 opacity-100'>click to browse</span></p>
            <input required={true} type="file" name="singleImage" accept="image/*" className='z-10 w-full h-full absolute opacity-0' onChange={(e) => {setSingleImage(e.target.files[0])}}/>
          </div>
          
        </div>
        <label className='text-blue-900'>Product Images <span className='text-red-500'>*</span></label>
        <div className='grid grid-cols-4'>
        { MultipleImagesSrc.length > 0 ? (
          MultipleImagesSrc.map((image, i) => (
            <div key={i} className='relative group h-[232px] w-full rounded-xl overflow-hidden border-2'>
              <img
                src={image}  // Properly setting the base64 string here
                className='w-full h-full absolute'
                alt={`image-${i}`}  // Giving a unique alt attribute
              />
              <div className='group-hover:opacity-20 transition-all bg-black h-full absolute opacity-0 w-full'></div>
              <button className='absolute right-0' onClick={() => {MultipleImagesSrc.splice(i, 1)}}>
                <i className='bx bx-x text-red-500 invisible group-hover:visible absolute m-2 text-[30px] right-0'></i>
              </button>
            </div>
          ))
        ) : (
          <div className='hidden'></div>
        )}
          
          <div className='flex flex-col justify-center items-center text-center py-14 px-5 overflow-hidden relative border h-fit '>
            <i class='bx bx-cloud-upload text-blue-900 text-[3em]'></i>
            <p className='w-[80%] '><span className='opacity-60'>Drop your images here or select</span> <span className='text-blue-900 opacity-100'>click to browse</span></p>
            <input required={true} type="file" name="singleImage" accept="image/*" className='z-10 w-full h-full absolute opacity-0' multiple onChange={(e) => {setMultipleImages(e.target.files)}}/>
          </div>
          
        </div>
        <input type="submit" value="save" className='bg-blue-900 w-fit text-white pb-1 px-3 rounded-lg ' />
      </form>
    </div>
  )
}

export default EditContent


I tried to map the MultipleImagesSrc after I checked that it contained the base 64 of the images, but it did not preview it.
The problem:
The multiple images do not display as expected right after they are uploaded. I suspect it may be related to how I'm handling the state updates for the image previews.
The current method of rendering MultipleImagesSrc may not be working correctly.
Environment:
Next.js
React
Using Tailwind CSS for styling

Possibly the problem is with your base64 data of your images take a look here  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8499633/how-to-display-base64-images-in-html

If you want to display an image from base64 data, then you need to have the following information in your src information before the actual data:
src="data:image/jpeg;charset=utf-8;base64,{your-data-here}
On a side note, why have you duplicated the multiple images src in a UseState hook and as a normal array?

the problem is the .map do not even create the div its not the problem of the src i think , because the form of the data passed to the src is good , here is an example of console.log(MultipleImagesSrc[0] : data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD//gAfQ29tcHJlc3NlZCBieSBqcGVnLXJlY29tcHJlc3P/4QAYRXhpZgAASUkqAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAP/sABFEdWNreQABAAQAAABk.....
